# header('Content-Disposition: attachment') not triggering when using with curl

Tags: php, curl, header, content-disposition

I am exporting some invoices in json in my `XmlController.php` and converting them in xml in my `xml_export.php`

In my `XmlController.php`:

```
private function exportBills() {
    $bill_ids = $this->_getParam('bill_ids');
    $bill_model = new Model_Bills();
    $bills = $bill_model->findByIds($bill_ids);
    $data = array('bills' => array());

    $extract = array();
    foreach($bills as $bill) {
        $data['bills'][] = $bill->getJsonView();
        $extract[$bill->bill_reference_number] = $bill;
    }

    try {
        $response = $this->post('xml_export.php', $data);
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(200);
        return;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->view->error = 'Unknown Error';
        $this->view->description = $e->getMessage();
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
        return;
    }
}

private function post($url, $data) {
    $data = json_encode($data);
    $headers = array_merge(
        array(
            'Accept: application/xml',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data),
            'Origin: ' . get_base_url()));
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

    $xml = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if(false === $xml) {
        throw new Exception('cURL failed! URL was: ' . $url);
    }
}
```

And in my `xml_export.php`:

```
require_once('../library/functions.php');
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

try{
    $input = json_decode($json, true);
    $response = array();
    $xml_string = null;
    $xml_concat = null;
    if(implode('', array_keys($input)) === 'invoices') {
        foreach ($input['invoices'] as $invoice) { 
            $xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><data></data>');
            array_to_xml($invoice, $xml_data);
            $xml = $xml_data->asXML();
            $xml = preg_replace('~<(\d)~', '<number$1', $xml);
            $xml = preg_replace('~<\/(\d)~', '</number$1', $xml);

            $domxml = new DOMDocument('1.0');
            $domxml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
            $domxml->formatOutput = true;
            $domxml->loadXML($xml);
            $xml_string = $domxml->saveXML();

            $xml_concat .= $xml_string;
        }
    }elseif(implode('', array_keys($input)) === 'bills') {
        foreach ($input['bills'] as $bill) { 
            $xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><data></data>');
            array_to_xml($bill, $xml_data);
            $xml = $xml_data->asXML();
            $xml = preg_replace('~<(\d)~', '<number$1', $xml);
            $xml = preg_replace('~<\/(\d)~', '</number$1', $xml);

            $domxml = new DOMDocument('1.0');
            $domxml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
            $domxml->formatOutput = true;
            $domxml->loadXML($xml);
            $xml_string = $domxml->saveXML();

            $xml_concat .= $xml_string;
        }
    }

    file_put_contents('/tmp/report.xml', print_r(htmlspecialchars($xml_concat), true));

    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="report.xml"');
    echo $xml_concat;
    readfile('/tmp/report.xml');
    exit;

}catch(OAuthException $e){
    die('Unable to export.  Please contact support for assistance');
}
```

My `$xml_concat` definitely has output and my `/tmp/report.xml` also exists and has output but the download was not triggered.

Below is my reponse header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-  check=0
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 26 Mar 2016 14:47:22 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.16-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

and my request header:

```
POST /v1/xml HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 81
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.108 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

I am not exactly sure why it is in `application/json` when I specified in `application/xml` in my controller and the headers did not pick up the content-disposition.

Comment: Which bit of that PHP code is actually supposed to handle  requests to `/v1/xml`?

Comment: @Quentin That is the zend framework's route redirecting to `XmlController.php`. Do you think that might be the problem? I do get the output in my `xml_export.php` so I don't think it is redirection issue.

Comment: OK, so `/v1/xml` hits `XmlController.php`. Where does `xml_export.php` come into it? I can't see anywhere that `XmlController.php` references it.

Comment: @Quentin I edited the question to include the function that references it in the controller. I originally omitted because I think the problem mainly exists at the post function.

Comment: It looks like you're making a request from JS to PHP which triggers an HTTP request from PHP to PHP. The headers you are setting are on the response to the second request and the code from the first request isn't relaying them to the JS.

Comment: @Quentin so in theory to resolve this I should keep the convertion within the controller instead of separating it out into 2 files that way it can be returned back to the JS in the frontend?

Comment: Yes. I don't understand why you are fetching the XML using HTTP instead of a simple function call though.

Comment: (It's probably also worth pointing out, before you go any further, that a content-disposition header in a response to a request by `XMLHttpRequest` won't have any practical effect beyond making its value available to `getRequestHeader`)

Comment: @Quentin I think I understand now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i guess you have some retarded framework that takes the `Accept: application/json` request header a little too seriously.. try changing it to `Accept: */*`